# AngularJS - how to put double quotes around a variable passed from a form

Tags: angularjs

I am an AngularJS leaner. Please how do I put double quotes around a variable passed from a form in AngularJS. I am trying to compose a Json string which is sent to an RO Server using $Resource:

```
    app.controller('VanDeleteCtrl', ['$scope','$resource', 'VansFactory', 'VanDeleteFactory', '$location',
                                    function ($scope, $resource,VansFactory, VanDeleteFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'deleteVan':                                                               
        $scope.deleteCard=function(vanNumber) {

            var vanNoObject=
            {
                      "cardNumber" : {
                        "value" : <<the vanNumber param should be here in double quotes>>
e.g. "value":"12344444"
                       }
            };      
             VanDeleteFactory.save(vanNoObject); 
         }

      }]);
```

Comment: To convert a number into a string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you need to add double quotes. Are you sure it's the real problem?

Anyway you should be able to achieve it like that:

```
var vanNoObject =
{
    cardNumber : {}
};
vanNoObject.cardNumber.value = '' + vanNumber;
```

Concatenating an empty string with a number wil convert your number to a string.

I removed the quotes around cardNumber; it's because vanNoObject is a [Javascript Object Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), and not JSON; it's not the exact same notation. They are not required it the property name is a valid identifier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ITS NOW RESOLVED .... I code was passing a form object ... So I had to do formname.vanNumber to get the value ... No need for casting of any type. Thanks a lot.